# filter and field on array collection in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In this array collection, I want to filter only those array elements that are due. How can I use a filter query on an array collection?

```
  0 => array:7 [
    "semester" => "1"
    "fee_head" => "4"
    "fee_due_date" => "2018-04-07 00:00:00"
    "fee_amount" => 18000
    "discount" => 0
    "fine" => 0
    "paid_amount" => 1200
  ]
  1 => array:7 [
    "semester" => "1"
    "fee_head" => "4"
    "fee_due_date" => "2018-04-07 00:00:00"
    "fee_amount" => 18000
    "discount" => 0
    "fine" => 0
    "paid_amount" => 18000
  ]
```

**Calculating Due:** 
$due = (fee_amount - (discount+paid_amount))+fine
if($due>0) 
then I want to get following output

```
0 => array:7 [
            "semester" => "1"
            "fee_head" => "4"
            "fee_due_date" => "2018-04-07 00:00:00"
            "fee_amount" => 1800
            "discount" => 0
            "fine" => 0
            "paid_amount" => 1200
             "due"  => 600
      ]
```

Comment: do you have a query of this collection ? also show your code

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Map](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-map) and [Filter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-filter) functions of the [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections) class. You can try this:

```php
    $filtered = collect($your_original_array)->map(function ($item) {
                // Creating the 'due' key
                $item['due'] = ($item['fee_amount'] - ($item['discount'] + $item['paid_amount'])) + $item['fine'];
                return $item;

            })->filter(function ($item) {
                return $item['due'] > 0;
            });

    return $filtered;
```

PD: Have not test it yet (this should work tho) but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it in your query before you get that collections.

```
YourModel::where('semester',1) // (other  filters)
        ->select(DB::raw('
            semester, fee_head, fee_due_date
            SUM(fee_amount) as  fee_amount,
            SUM(discount) as discount,
            SUM(fine) as fine,
            SUM(paid_amount) as paid_amount,
            (SUM(fee_amount) - (SUM(discount) + SUM(paid_amount)) + SUM(fine)) as due

        '))
        ->groupBy('semester') //
        ->get();
```

this answer is an alternative way to your query